# What does the recommendation to use `set` for setting shell options in Google's Shell Style Guide mean?

Tags: bash, shell-script

[From Google's Shell Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#which-shell-to-use):

> Bash is the only shell scripting language permitted for executables.
>
> Executables must start with `#!/bin/bash` and a minimum number of flags. Use `set` to set shell options so that calling your script as `bash script_name` does not break its functionality.

Specifically, the part about using `set` to avoid breaking functionality. And what does calling it in that particular way have to do with it?

Comment: I believe this Google guide strictly applies only to scripts hosted in their Cloud service. It has some reasonable advice, but is excessively over-prescriptive in places.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant the style guide isn’t prescriptive for Google’s cloud services, it applies to code developed by Google. See [the general description](https://google.github.io/styleguide/) for context.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The "and a minimum number of flags" refers to flags set in the hashbang line. They'd be read when the script is started as `./somescript`, and the kernel reads the hashbang line, building a new argument list from the path and options found there. But this does *not* happen if the script is started as `bash somescript`, as the kernel is asked to run `bash`, and not the script itself. The shell itself sees the line as a comment to be ignored when eventually reading the script.

For example, try the following script (in `./hello`):

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo hello
```

And run it in both of the two ways:

```
$ ./hello
+ echo hello
hello
$ bash hello
hello
```

The extra trace output from `-x` is shown only in the first case, the flag is ignored with the second invocation.

Enabling the flag explicitly with a `set` command would make it work the same either way:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
echo hello
```

<sup>(though note that if you ever try this with `perl`, it *does* interpret the hashbang line itself, too.)</sup>

Comment: from the same guide (and some Unix guide of old) "Executables should have no extension". Using a file extension to mark the language, breaks encapsulation.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, hah, well, yes. But source code files usually do have an extension (be it `.c` or `.pl` or `.py`), so maybe that's where the habit has come. Also some editors look at the extension to guess the language...

Comment: Naming scripts with an extension is useful with Makefile projects that build releases: it means you can construct rules that handle copying and permissions (and remove the extension from the released/installed version).

Comment: For tools that need a file extension, I often create a sym-link. I have never had a problem with editors, they just seem to work. However on MS-windows (with no Unix sub-system), I need to add a `.py` extension to python programs. I don't get the problem with leaked implementation, as I don't get close to a lever of functionality that would cause it.

Comment: Great explanation. By the way, why do people even put the flags in the shebang line? Seems needlessly adventurous.

Comment: @typo, maybe they want to save typing the three letters from `set`... Perhaps some might also not know that it's possible to use `set -x` instead. Who knows. In some cases you have to do it, though. E.g. with awk and expect the hashbang needs to be `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`, because they need the `-f` option to point to a file on the command line. And in Perl, there are some settings that can only be set there, and not after the interpreter actually initializes (`-T` for taint checking at least). But I don't _think_ there's any such reason with the shell.

Comment: @ilkkachu: I believe that the `-p` (lower-case `P` = “privileged” mode) flag must be specified on the invocation of the shell (i.e., on the hashbang) in order to be effective.  Clearly this is true for the `--norc` option as well, and maybe also `--login`, ``--rcfile `` *`file`* and `--posix`.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica', yep, I should have written "I can't think of any". There's `set -p`, which drops extra privileges, but probably doesn't undo importing functions (`bash -p` prevents the import). `--login` or `-l` probably has no equivalent, at least it's listed in the man page separate from `set` options. And it affects startup files too, like `--rcfile`, and there's no way to do that after startup. There's `set -o posix`, which probably does the same as `--posix`, except if there was some difference to startup files here, too.